# Are headphones with EMF measurement of 10,000 milligauss harmful to me?

Tags: immune-system, radiation, radioactivity, bioelectromagnetics

I used an [Electric-Magnetic Field detector app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mreprogramming.ultimateemfdetector) on my phone and measured the EMF output on my wired headphones. It measured around 10,000 milligauss (1mT) on one part of both ear cups. Since wearing these headphones on my head for long periods of time, will this cause injury to my head or immune system?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren’t.

> In the area of biological effects and medical applications of non-ionizing radiation approximately 25,000 articles have been published over the past 30 years. Despite the feeling of some people that more research needs to be done, scientific knowledge in this area is now more extensive than for most chemicals. Based on a recent in-depth review of the scientific literature, the WHO concluded that current evidence does not confirm the existence of any health consequences from exposure to low level electromagnetic fields. However, some gaps in knowledge about biological effects exist and need further research.

[WHO](https://www.who.int/peh-emf/about/WhatisEMF/en/index1.html)